# How can I get command history for console-based debugging in PyCharm?

Tags: debugging, console, pycharm, pdb

When I use PyCharm I find myself frequently trying out pieces of code interactively. So far, my workflow has been to use `pdb`for this and set a breakpoint as `pdb.set_trace`, which then drops me into the console.

However, for PyCharm the resulting console has no command history - the up arrow instead moves the cursor upwards into the previous output, which is a pain to use.

I realize there's also the built-in debugger that has a console with history, but getting there involves more clicks (run the debugger, switch to Console tab and clicking on "Show Python Prompt").

There is a built-in console that does have a command history (Tools > Python Console), however, unfortunately that's not the console that's being run for `pdb`break points. Is it possible to get PyCharm to use a different console for `pdb`?

Comment: Or a way to get Python to drop to the console rather than the variables when "Always show console in debug mode" is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. PyCharm has no control over what happens when you invoke pdb.set_trace().

Comment: When I run my script from the built-in Python console (Tools > Python Console) the command history works - which makes me think that this is a UI problem rather than having to do with `pdb`.